# How to use Richfaces skinning on standard table?

Tags: css, richfaces

From my understanding at the Richfaces [demo page](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/standardSkinning.jsf?c=StandardSkinning&tab=usage#) and [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html#Skinnability), I should be able to skin standard HTML elements.

> This feature provides styling for standard HTML form elements in order to be highly compilant with RichFaces common look'n'feel.

I may be a little burnt out with RF today, but I don't see how to get skinning on regular elements. For example if I wanted a hand made table to match the fancy Richfaces tables I would have thought something like this would work:

```
<table class="rich-table">
        <tr class="rich-tr">
        <a4j:repeat value="#{myBean.elements}" var="e">
            <th class="rich-th" >
                                   <h:outputText value="#{e.text}" />
                            </th>
                    </a4j:repeat>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

Other elements I've tried to skin haven't been working either, so I feel I am going at this the wrong way. The ultimate goal is to have standard HTML elements blend in and still allow the skins to be swapped from say blueSky to emeraldGreen w/o changing specific elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Add this context parameter: org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING to web.xml and set it to 'enable'. I'm not 100% sure it will skin a table tag. If not, you can use #{richSkin.any_param_name} to skin the table manually.

Comment: I have CONTROL_SKINNING enabled. Can you give an example of how to use the `richSkin` bean?

Comment: I was able to find an example of using the richSkin bean here: http://www.packtpub.com/article/skin-customization-in-jboss-richfaces-3.3

Comment: Good, it's something like this: #{richSkin.panelBorderColor}. Sorry I wasn't more clear. You can use any skin parameter.

Comment: I found the docs which helped: http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html#StControlsSkinning

Answer (score 2):

There problem is - **richFaces doesn't come with a "static table" tag**, and **does not provide automatic skinning of tables**, because of "blablabla" (some lame excuse ;) ). And manual skinning is awful.

**The solution: use rich:dataTable, providing some dummy value** (*rich:dataTable value="DummyStaticValue"*) and use *rich:columnGroup* together with *rich:column*.

Your combination will only be rendered once (because of the dummyValue being just a string), and you can get any table structure you want.

```
<rich:dataTable width="100%" value="DummyStaticValue">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="myHeader" />
    </f:facet>
    <rich:columnGroup>
        <rich:column>
            <h:outputText value="myValue1" />
        </rich:column>
        <rich:column>
            <h:outputText value="myValue2" />
        </rich:column>
    </rich:columnGroup>
    <rich:columnGroup>
        <rich:column>
            <h:outputText value="myValue3" />
        </rich:column>
        <rich:column>
            <h:outputText value="myValue4" />
        </rich:column>
    </rich:columnGroup>
```